# UTP cable issue

Tags: utp

I had LAN cables installed in my home with sockets in the walls in the house and terminating in the garage with RJ45 connectors (router sits there).

I have been using one such connection for over 5 years but a couple of months ago I started having intermittent problems. I thought it was an issue with my desktop, but eventually it stopped working completely. I finally came to the conclusion that it was the cable and bought a cheap cable tester and established that 2 wires were not working (3 and 7).

I've hardly ever touched these cables, so is it more likely that the issue is with the cable or with the connectors? It seems it will be very difficult to get a new cable to the same location. What could be the cause of such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some animal. Or a nail in the wall. Or one of those connectors are broken, just try to replace them, it's easy. Maybe you'll be able to bond new cable with the old one and replace it that way, you just pull it on the other side. But first things first, try the connectors.

Answer (score 1):

As Caesar mentioned, try replacing the connectors first.  If that doesn't work and replacing the cable is not an option (NB: *I would only suggest this for a home, non-commercial installation*), swap the green pair with the blue pair so your connectors (both ends!) look like this:

```
1 -> orange/white
2 -> orange
3 -> blue/white (normally green/white here)
4 -> green/white
5 -> green
6 -> blue (normally green)
7 -> brown/white
8 -> brown
```

Normally only pins 1, 2, 3 and 6 are used so don't worry about your damaged brown/white wire.  Yes, your wiring won't match specs, but it's your home so nobody but you (or the next owner) will ever know.